# Redrawing images on c# form

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap, system.drawing

I have some troubles with redrawing images on c# Windows forms. I have some images to be drawn on panel. Everytime a **panel_Paint** event is raised, i draw my images. Everything was nice, untill I started to scroll my panel. The "redrawing" is for some reason noticeble to human eye. I mean, you can watch how the place, where image takes place, is for a very small time empty and image is drawn upon that place a bit later. This effect appeares each time I redraw my images. This effect reminds me the same as, when a Person scrolls something in folder on a PC without Graphic Card drivers installed.
Can i get rid of these visible "redrawings"?
I wish i could scroll my images without any lag.
I invalidate my panel with images, each time i move my mouse over other panel(this panel is some sort of scrollbar, that i am trying to implement).
EDIT: Problem resolved

Comment: I guess you draw your image in some `Tick` event handler of a `Timer`?

Comment: I invalidate my panel with images each time i move my mouse over other panel(this panel is some sort of scrollbar, that i am trying to implement).

Comment: Is your `Image` large enough? Because if it's large the issue may occur, otherwise I've never encounter such an issue with drawing image in `winforms`.

Comment: Image is about 200x200.

Comment: All I can suggest you now is try enabling the `DoubleBuffered` like this: `typeof(Control).GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(yourPanel, true, null);`. That's called Reflection, the `BindingFlags` is located in the namespace `System.Reflection`. It's used mainly when the image is large and we need to draw much stuff without any flicker.

Comment: Founded the reason of this flickering. I created a Graphics object each time my images were redrawn instead of using e.Graphics. But thanks ;)

Comment: Also, calling `Invalidate()` on anything is not as responsive as calling `Refresh()` and `Update()`, depending on what other things you have to paint in there.